# Single object hierarchy, multiple backing databases in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, multiple-databases

I have these classes:

```
class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     string Email { get; set; }
}

class Model1 
{ 
    Model2 Model2 { get; set }
    Model3 Model3 { get; set }
    User User { get; set; }
}

class Model2 
{
    User User2 { get; set; }
}

class Model3
{ 
    User User3 { get; set; }
}
```

(In practice the Model hierarchy is deeper and has many other properties. The important thing is that the User class is referenced in several different places of the Model hierarchy.)

I am in the process of mapping this class hierarchy using EF. I am forced to use *two distinct* relational databases, a legacy "UserDB" which already maps the User class, but which I otherwise cannot touch; and a "ModelDB" which is under my control. Similarly, I can change the `Model[123]` but not the `User` class(es). Client code using `Model[123]` must have access to a `User User` property.

EF does not support inter-database joins. I tried to emulate one, like this:  I added a `int UserId` field accompanying `User User` to all of `Model[123]`, then marked `User User` as `[NotMapped]`. The question is when to resolve these ids into actual `User` objects. The options seem to be:

1. Manually fixup the `Model` hierarchy by traversing it and loading missing `User User` properties immediately after each EF query to `ModernDB`.
2. Make the `User User` properties lazy, and have them resolve upon first access.

Neither option seems good: Option (1) is error prone and repetitive; Option (2) introduces what should be asynchronous operations in calls that client code should be able to assume is asynchronous. (Also, I seemed to very easily introduce deadlocks when I tried.)

Does EF have a hook that allows me to run asynchronous code when an EF-entity is populated?

Is there a good way to emulate inter-database joins in EF?

Comment: EF isn't a database model or embedded SQL. DbSets aren't tables. A DbContext isn't a database, it's a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. You shouldn't need any of this. If you can write cross-database queries, you can map *entities* to database objects, whether tables, views or aliases.

Comment: On the other hand, you really don't want to let EF just include tables from other databases or linked servers by itself, because the resulting query can have serious performance issues. For example, when using a linked table SQL Server can't guess what indexes or statistics are used remotely and will try to pull the remote data locally. That can be very bad for large tables.

Comment: I *do* need to have a single object hierarchy which is mapped to two distinct backing databases. My attempted approach may certainly be mistaken, though. What is the right way to proceed?

Comment: What error are you getting?  It sound like a cross threading issue and may need to use invoke.

Comment: No you don't. A DbContext isn't your entity model any more that it's a database model. You can use the same class in multiple DbContexts. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work for a specific business scenario. It tracks all changes made during a specific UoW and persists all of them when SaveChanges is called, by generating SQL statements that execute in a single internal transaction. Nothing prevents you from using the same entity in multiple business scenarios and hence, multiple UoWs or DbContexts. OTOH, the `User` of an authentication database contains fields that aren't needed in Sales

Comment: @jdweng the OP is talking about cross-database JOINs. It seems they tried to use LINQ JOIN with two DbContexts, trying to emulate a SQL JOIN.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Help me understand my misunderstanding here: I'm given an existing model hierarchy (Model123) and an existing database (UserDb). I'm tasked with serialising this model hierarchy to a new database (ModernDb), using EF. How should I go about this?

Comment: Which database are you using? In SQL Server the easiest solution would be to create a [SYNONYM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-create-a-synonym-for-a-local-object) pointing to UserDB.Users, eg `CREATE SYNONYM Users For UserDB.dbo.Users`. You can use the same `User` class in both UserDbContext and ModelDbContext

Comment: I need this to function on a a local SQLite and a remote SQL server.